# How to use loadjsfile in .NET Core in a View class?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have the following code that I have migrated from .NET to .NET Core.

Unfortunately, the javascript files are not being loaded with the loadjsfile. What can I use to be able to load these javascript files into my View Class?

```
<script>
    function loadjsfile(filename) {
        var fileref = document.createElement("script");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
        document.writeln(fileref.outerHTML);
    };
    if (jQuery == undefined) loadjsfile(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"));

    loadjsfile(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"));
    loadjsfile(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
    loadjsfile(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/contactusform.js");

</script>
```

Currently, I know for sure that "contactusform.js" is not being loaded because I call a javascript method in one of the input buttons and it says that the method cannot be found.

Comment: This is Javascript, and not really anything to do with core. All you probably need to worry about it the `Url.Content` bits. Check your web browser console for any errors.

Comment: What does `loadjsfile` do ? Why not use script tag to include your js files ?

Comment: @Shyju Looks like it loads jQuery if it's not already been defined. Could be handy for CDN going down for example.

Comment: @DavidG previously the code was `loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js");` and I was trying to implement it into .NET Core, do you think that I should just get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `loadjsfile` method take a string value, you should wrap the result of your `Url.Content` call in quotes.

```
loadjsfile("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")");
```

You may also consider using the script tag helper with `asp-fallback-src` attribute.

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
    </script> 
</environment>
```

Update the `asp-fallback-src` value to your local copy of the library.

Comment: How would this help if (and this is guessing) the code is inside a partial view and jQuery was supposed to be added outside? **Edit:** Your edit is more likely the right answer, the extra info is a useful addition though.

Comment: I have previously tried to wrap it in quotes just like you have it in your answer but it did not change the result. I should have mentioned it in my question. maybe the connection problem is somewhere else...

Comment: So i suggest you look into the code of `loadjsfile` method and see what it tries to do.  As i mentioned in the answer, you may also consider using the tag helpers

Comment: I think wrapping it in quotes actually fixed the issue now, I was just not aware of the change of errors, now it is not a connection error but something else. I will try to implement the tag helpers as well